# UI hangs when adding large data in pivot item for WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, async-await

I am creating a dynamic pivot. In which I have binded a collection to pivot ItemSouce. When the selectionchange event is fired I am calling a process which takes some time and the update the ObservableCollection which in turn update the UI. I am using async and await but still the application UI hangs.
Let me know what is the issue. Looking for a very quick reply.

CODE:

```
 private void CraetePivotItems()
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++)
            {
                EntityDetail item = new EntityDetail();
                item.HeaderTitle = "Header " + count;
                item.Name = string.Empty;

                this.Detaildata.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> CreateUserControlForPivotItem(int selectedIndex)
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < 1000000000; count++)
            {
            }

            switch (selectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    return "Item 1";
                case 1:
                    return "Item 2";
                case 2:
                    return "Item 3";
                default:
                    return "Item N";
            }
        }

        private void pvtItmCities_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CraetePivotItems();

            this.pvtItmCities.ItemsSource = this.Detaildata;
        }

        private async void pvtItmCities_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {

                ////// Create the user control for the selected pivot item
                string pivotItemContentControl = await CreateUserControlForPivotItem(((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex);

                (this.Detaildata[((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex] as EntityDetail).Name = pivotItemContentControl;

                //((System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl)((sender as Pivot).SelectedItem)).Content = pivotItemContentControl;
            }
        }
```

Class

```
internal class EntityDetail : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string headerTitle = String.Empty;
        public string HeaderTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return this.headerTitle;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.headerTitle)
                {
                    this.headerTitle = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private string name = String.Empty;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.name)
                {
                    this.name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplateSample">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderTitle}" Foreground="White"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateSample">
            <local:PivotItem1Content  Foreground="White"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<phone:Pivot x:Name="pvtItmCities" 

                     HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplateSample}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSample}"
                     SelectionChanged="pvtItmCities_SelectionChanged" Loaded="pvtItmCities_Loaded" Title="pivot demo" LoadingPivotItem="OnLoadingPivotItem">

        </phone:Pivot>
```

What is the issue??

Comment: Just putting the `async` keyword doesn't ensure that your method will execute in a separate thread. Explicitly create a new Task in the `CreateUserControlForPivotItem` method to do all the processing, remove the `async` keyword, and return that task.

Comment: I have created a tasks and updated the UI on ContinueWith and TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() but whe it updates the UI following issue occur An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Weird, it would mean that you're not in the UI thread when calling `askScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`. Can you try using the Dispatcher to update the UI?

Comment: Ok got it I will use dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that you create manually a separate thread and assign it to the function and it will update the UI thread when its finish. using Async Await doesn't mean that this is going to be on a different thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

this link show you how to assign a background worker (thread) to complete your tasks

i hope this will help you